# Call col name with min value (NA included)

Tags: r

I have df including NA.

```
 df <- data.frame( X1= c(NA, 1, 4, NA), 
             X2 = c(34, 75, 1, 4), 
             X3= c(2,9,3,5))
```

My ideal out come looks like,

```
  X1 X2 X3 Min
1 NA 34  2 X3
2  1 75  9 X1
3  4  1  3 X2
4 NA  4  5 X2
```

I have tried

```
df$Min <- colnames(df)[apply(df,1,which.min, na.rm=TRUE)]
```

but this one didn't work

Comment: If my solution helped to solve the problem you can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the na.rm=TRUE when using which.min() – try this instead:

```
df$Min <- colnames(df)[apply(df,1,which.min)]
```

Output:

```
  X1 X2 X3 Min
1 NA 34  2  X3
2  1 75  9  X1
3  4  1  3  X2
4 NA  4  5  X2
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
foo <- names(df)
df$Min <- apply(df, 1, function(x) foo[which.min(x)])
df
```

Output:

```
  X1 X2 X3 Min
1 NA 34  2  X3
2  1 75  9  X1
3  4  1  3  X2
4 NA  4  5  X2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea that will likely be faster and does not require any looping.  You could replace `NA` with `Inf`, take the negative of the data, then find the maximum per column via `max.col()`.

```
names(df)[max.col(-replace(df, is.na(df), Inf))]
# [1] "X3" "X1" "X2" "X2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, not to forget, a `data.table` solution, given that `dt <- as.data.table(df)`

```
dt[ , Min:=names(dt)[match(min(.SD, na.rm=T), .SD)], by=1:nrow(dt)][]
#   X1 X2 X3 Min
#1: NA 34  2  X3
#2:  1 75  9  X1
#3:  4  1  3  X2
#4: NA  4  5  X2
```

Not much simpler than the solutions above, just extending the choices here.